# What is the backslash in a Clojure REPL?

Tags: string, clojure, character

I am working in a Clojure REPL, and I see backslashes when I run some commands.  Some quick googling did not turn up any obvious answers.

If I run

```
Clojure 1.8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_91-b14
   (nth "I heart Clojure!" 4)
=> \a
```

What is the backslash here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the character(s) following should be interpreted as a literal.

- Characters - preceded by a backslash: \c. \newline, \space, \tab, \formfeed, \backspace, and \return yield the corresponding characters.
- Unicode characters - are represented with \uNNNN as in Java.
- Octals - are represented with \oNNN.

See the following links for more info.

- [Reading Clojure Characters: \ - Character literal](https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters#__code_code_character_literal)
- [The Reader: Literals](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_literals)

Answer (score 2):

In Clojure characters start with a backlash. More information on Clojure syntax can be found in the [Reader documentation](https://clojure.org/reference/reader).

Answer (score 2):

When you see a slash before a single character, that means it's not a string, but a Java Char instance:

```
user=> (type \a)
java.lang.Character
```

In both Java and Clojure, a String instance is considered as a sequence of characters. That's why `(nth ... 4)` returns the forth character in your example.

Also, slashes are used inside strings to quote some other characters. Say, to put a double quote inside a string, you need to prepend it with backslash:

```
(def message "User \"John\" not found")
;; User "John" not found
```

And finally, a backslash might specify a machine-wise symbol that stands for line ending, tab or whatever:

```
(def header "Name\tAge\tCity")
```

Here, `\t` means a `<TAB>` symbol. The header string will be printed like this:

```
Name        Age        City
```